# Why are the header search paths not used building from the command line?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to build a XCode workspace with `xcodebuild` 9.4.1.

Here is my command line:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/VAPoc.xcworkspace \
           -scheme VAPoc \
           -configuration 'Release' \
           -sdk iphoneos
```

Sadly it fails using header search paths specified in the XCode GUI.

I have to put them again on the command line for the build to succeed:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/VAPoc.xcworkspace \
           -scheme VAPoc \
           -configuration 'Release' \
           -sdk iphoneos \
           USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="$(inherited) /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/include /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/"
```

Building in XCode works like a charm...

I'm hoping someone could explain this to me.

It seems that I have to specify absolute paths here, and that I can't use environment variables? Am I right?

I have a workaround on my Mac but the problem is that my app will be built by [AppCenter in the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/first-build) and AFAIK I've no way to set build settings for `xcodebuild` in this environment. For now I think I'll need the header paths to be used from the xcodeproj file(s).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven’t tried it but would it make sense to use standard environment variables (predefined by Apple) that represent the path with respect to your project ?

Comment: I've tried CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH but it gets reset during the build...

Comment: If there was some environment variable to get your JVM path it might help. Or a way for you to build the path from your JVM path